# Angular: how test component defined in shared module

Tags: angular, unit-testing, testbed

I'm trying to write an unit test for a component that is defined in the main entry module. Since this component uses other components that are defined in shared module, I'd like to mock them instead of creating them. So, I've started by mocking the components. Here's an example:

```
@Component({ selector: "frt-dados-gerais", template: "" })
class DadosGeraisStubComponent {
    @Input() utilizador: DadosUtilizadorInstancia;
    @Input() gravacaoEmCurso = false;
    @Output() atualizaDadosGerais = new EventEmitter<InfoDadosGerais>();
}
```

Now, since my shared module is exporting the `frt-dados-gerais` component, I've tried to override the module with code that looks like this:

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [
            HttpClientTestingModule,
            NoopAnimationsModule,
            RouterTestingModule.withRoutes(rotas),
            BrowserModule,
            ReactiveFormsModule,
            PanelModule,
            GrowlModule,
            CoreModule,
            SharedModule
        ],
        declarations: [
            DadosPessoaisComponent,
            DadosGeraisStubComponent,
            PalavraChaveStubComponent,
            FuncoesDesempenhadasStubComponent,
            IndisponibilidadeMotoristaStubComponent
        ],
        providers: [
            { provide: UtilizadoresService, useValue: servicoUtilizadores },
            { provide: AutenticacaoService, useValue: servicoAutenticacao },
            { provide: ConfirmationService, useValue: utilizadoresService}
        ]
    })
    .overrideModule(SharedModule, {
        remove: {
            exports: [
                DadosPessoaisComponent,
                DadosGeraisComponent,
                FuncoesDesempenhadasComponent,
                IndisponibilidadeMotoristaComponent,
                DadosGeraisComponent
            ]
        }

    })
```

As you can see, I've tried cancelling the exports so that I don't get and error saying that the component has two definitions. I'm clearly missing something because I'm always getting the `NullInjectorError: No provider for DadosPessoaisComponent` error.

Can someone help?

**EDIT:** ok, finally figure it out. Such a stupid mistake...So, I was using `TestBed.get` instead of `TestBed.createComponent` to create the component under test...That's why I was getting the `NullInjectorError` exception...

Comment: Just a guess, but perhaps another one of the modules you are importing declares a component that injects `DadosPessoaisComponent`.  Also, do you need to import `SharedModule` into the TestBed at all?  Only import what is absolutely necessary to test the component of interest.

Comment: yes, I started by doing that, but since the component that I want to test uses stuff from he shared module, I had to add it to the import list... anyway, I've tried to remove it and I still get the same null injector error...